# Nodejs module.exports - Change variable value from other js file

Tags: node.js, request, module.exports

I export a variable value from file1.js to file2.js and it works okay, but if I want to change the value of that variable from file2.js in file1.js it doesn't work. 
Does this work for reading only, if so how can I connect these two files that I can change value from one to another file and vice versa?

Update: 
If in file1.js I have `let count = 0`, and from file2.js I want to change the count value to `count = 2`, how do I change it cause it doesn't change for file1..

Update 2 - SOLVED:

file1.js

```
let var1 = 55 ;
    function testFunk(reVar, i){
       console.log(var1, 'file1')
      if( reVar == 'read' ){
        return var1
      } else if( reVar == 'change' ){
        console.log(' change ')
        var1 = var1 + i ;
        return var1
      }
    }


    module.exports = {  testFunk , var1 }
```

file2.js

```
 var file1 = require("./file1.js") ;
let var1 ; 

testFunk1( )
function testFunk1( ){
   setTimeout(() => {
     var1 = file1.testFunk( 'read') ;
     testFunk1( )
    }, 20);
}


 setInterval(() => {
    file1.testFunk('change', 1 ) ;
   console.log(  var1 , 'file1'  ) ;
  }, 1000);
```

This way I can read variable values from file1, change them, then read the changed value again. This is what I asked, hope you understand now. If you have any other better solution please show it..

Comment: please post your code of both files in question also.

Comment: Can anyone help?

Comment: I also didnt understand your question. could you please elobarate.

Comment: Updated solved.. If you have better solution please answer..

Answer (score 0):

In node js, you can read and change variables declared in other js files by using the process object. It works similar to the window object in the browser.

let us look at an example below

file1.js

```
module.exports = process.myGlobals = {name: "prince david", age: 45, married: true}
```

file2.js
we can access the variables declared in file1.js in file2.js as follows

```
let globals = require("./file1.js")

console.log(globals) // the output will be {name: "prince david", age: 45, married: true}
console.log(globals.name) // the output will be prince, david
console.log(globals.age) // the output will be, 45
// to change any of the properties which was defined in file1.js, we can do the following

globals.name = "some other name"
console.log(globals.name) // the output will be, some other name
globals = {programmer: true}
console.log(globals) // the output will be {programmer: true}
```

All of this is working because when we export a variable declared using the process object, we even pass its reference so if we change that variable in any other files, its initial value will also change